# How to find degree sequence of graph given input vertices and edges?

Tags: python

```
vertice = input("enter the vertices: ")
vertice = [x.strip(' ') for x in vertice.split(',')]

edge = input("enter the edges: ")
edge = [x.strip(' ') for x in edge.split(',')]

print("Number of vertices: ", len(vertice))
print("Number of edges: ", len(edge)
```

From here I am trying to find the degree sequence given an input like:
a,b,c for the vertices
and a-b,b-c,c-a for the edges. How do I do this with this type of input?
looking for an output like [2,2,2]

Comment: As you need a graph data structure. Instead of storing edges and vertices in a lists I would highly recommend creating more sophisticated graph structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the edges associated to each vertex:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> vertices = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> edges = ['a-b', 'a-c', 'b-c', 'd-a']
>>> degree = Counter(vertex for edge in edges for vertex in edge.split('-'))
>>> [degree[vertex] for vertex in vertices]
[3, 2, 2, 1]
```

In above `Counter` constructor takes in an iterable of items and returns a `dict` like object where the unique items are keys and values the respective counts.

```
>>> items = list(vertex for edge in edges for vertex in edge.split('-'))
>>> items
['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a']
>>> degree = Counter(items)
>>> degree
Counter({'a': 3, 'c': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 1})
```

Since the ordering of the `Counter` is random we need to use list comprehension to iterate over the vertices in order to generate list of degrees in the same order.

```
>>> [degree[vertex] for vertex in vertices]
[3, 2, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you! Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the networkx package - which gives you most, if not all, of the functionality you'd want manipulating a graph.  Say you have a path of 4 nodes radially connected you'd find the degree like this:

```
from networkx import nx
G = nx.Graph()  
G.add_path([0,1,2,3])
deg=G.degree(G.nodes()).values()
print("number of vertices: ",G.number_of_nodes())
print("number of edges: ",G.number_of_edges()) 
print("degree list: ",sorted(deg))

>>number of vertices: 4
>>number of edges: 3
>>degree list: [1, 1, 2, 2]
```